# Django query for top models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django model which every instance has an attribute of `item_id`. I want to query for the top item ids based on which has the most votes.

I have tried this with no success.

```
top_item_ids_as_vote = Vote.objects.annotate(item_count=Count('item_id')).order_by('item_count').distinct('item_id')
```

Comment: top models! LOL. Also, can you copy here your(s) models.

Comment: perhaps you forget [values list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) method in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
top_item_ids_as_vote = Vote.objects.annotate(item_count=Count('item_id')).order_by('-item_count')[:10]
```

Comment: The questioner wants *the top item ids*, may be you could give `values()` a try